# Factorial in JS at my interview at Sina Weibo

Tags: javascript, math

**how much 0 at the end of 1*2*3*....*100?**
for example
1 zero 10,2 zero at the end of 10100,0 zero at 10001
The interviewer gave me 3 mins.
front-end develope intern was the job i went for.
i tried to solve it in JavaScript,it was wrong because 100! is so big for a JS variable.Here is my code.

```
var factorial = function(x){
  if(x<0){
    return error;
  }else if (x ===1 || x ===0) {
    return x;
  }else if (x > 1) {
    return (factorial(x - 1) * x);
  }
}

var counter = 0;
var countZero = function(x){
  while((x%10) === 0){
    counter = counter + 1;
    x = x/10;
  }
  return counter;
}
console.log(countZero(factorial(100)));
```

Any ideas?I solved it without computer in a pure-math way,but i want to know how to solve it in JS.

Comment: `return error;` Trying to do that will result in a `ReferenceError`...

Comment: It's a bit of a silly question, since you would have to know a trick at least I had to google... https://brilliant.org/wiki/trailing-number-of-zeros/#factorials-in-base-ten

Comment: @AKX Yep, that's a poor interview question.

Comment: @AKX  I solved it exactly the same way in your link on my way home bus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A number gets a zero at the end of it if the number has 10 as a factor. For instance, 10 is a factor of 50, 120, and 1234567890. So you need to find out how many times 10 is a factor in the expansion of 100!.

But since 5×2 = 10, we need to account for all the products of 5 and 2. Looking at the factors in the above expansion, there are many more numbers that are multiples of 2 (2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14,...) than are multiples of 5 (5, 10, 15,...). That is, if we take all the numbers with 5 as a factor, We'll have way more than enough even numbers to pair with them to get factors of 10 (and another trailing zero on my factorial). So to find the number of times 10 is a factor, all we really need to worry about is how many times 5 is a factor in all of the numbers between 1 and 100

Okay, how many multiples of 5 are there in the numbers from 1 to 100? There's 5, 10, 15, 20, 25,...

Let's do this the short way: 100 is the closest multiple of 5 below or equal to 100, and 100 ÷ 5 = 20, so there are twenty multiples of 5 between 1 and 100.

But wait: 25 is 5×5, so each multiple of 25 has an extra factor of 5 that we need to account for. How many multiples of 25 are between 1 and 100? Since 100 ÷ 25 = 4, there are four multiples of 25 between 1 and 100.

Adding these, We get 20 + 4 = 24 trailing zeroes in 100!

**It was more of a math question that a Javascript specific question and you don't need to calculate the actual factorial to find the number of trailing zeros**

[More details here](https://www.purplemath.com/modules/factzero.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Zeros at the end of a number result from 2s and 5s being multiplied together. So, one way to count up the total number of zeros would be to figure out how many total 2s and 5s go into `100!` - don't *calculate* that number, just add up the number of factors - and then return whichever count (2s or 5s) is smallest.

```js
let twos = 0;
let fives = 0;
for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
  let num = i;
  while (num % 2 === 0) {
    twos++;
    num /= 2;
  }
  while (num % 5 === 0) {
    fives++;
    num /= 5;
  }
}
console.log(Math.min(twos, fives));
```

Answer (score 0):

For the numbers less or equal than `1000000000` as your case here you could use the following algorithm :

```js
function numberOfZeros(n) {
  if (n == 0) return 0;
  return parseInt(n * (n - 1) / (4 * n));
}
console.log(numberOfZeros(100));
```